# UIPickerView not displaying data even after requery

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uipickerview, rx-swift

Let's say I have a stream of dogs `private var dogs: Observable<[Dogs]>`. Every time a new value is produced my block is called where I create a new dataSource and delegate for my `UIPickerView` and then within the block I call `pickerView.reloadAllComponents()` but my view appears with an empty pickerView, even though the dataSource and delegate are queried.

Example code:

```
self.dataStream
        .subscribeNext {
            self.dataSource = PickerViewDataSource(data: $0)
            self.pickerView.dataSource = self.dataSource
            self.delegate = PickerViewDelegate(data: $0, selectedRow: self._selectedRowStream)
            self.pickerView.delegate = self.delegate
            self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        }.addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
```

Debugging the dataSource and delegate I know these are queried and the reason I am keep dataSource and delegate reference in the UIViewController is due to the fact that the `UIPickerView` holds a weak reference for these.

This one of the last strategies I have tried and still get the same result. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Update:

DogPickerViewDataSource:

```
class DogPickerViewDataSource: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    private var dogs: [Dog]

    init(
        dogs: [Dog]
    ) {
        self.dogs = dogs
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return dogs.count
    }
}
```

DogPickerViewDelegate:

```
class DogPickerViewDelegate: NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    private var selectedRow: BehaviorSubject<Int>
    private var dogs: [Dog]

    init(
        dogs: [Dog],
        selectedRow: BehaviorSubject<Int>
    ) {
        self.dogs = dogs
        self.selectedRow = selectedRow
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let dogName = (self.dogs[row].name)!
        return NSAttributedString(string: dogName)
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        self.selectedRow.onNext(row)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please also provide PickerViewDataSource's  UIPickerViewDataSource protocol implementation?

Comment: Have you debugged if any of UIPickerViewDataSource's or UIPickerViewDelegate's methods are getting called after reloadAllComponents function?

Comment: yes I have debugged them and yes they are being called after reloadAllComponents() method. Thats why I am puzzled.

Comment: Are you sure that you're displaying the same picker view for which dataSource and delegate methods are getting called?

Comment: Ok you are on to something, the pickerView only fails when the screen is invoked via another screen (unwind). It is not the same UIPickerView. But that should not be a problem in my opinion. The viewDidLoad() method is called again anyhow so it should recreate the dataSource and delegate after the unwind action and associating the new instances to the new instance of the pickerView

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, on viewDidLoad you're initialising your pickerView with new delegate and data source, calling reloadAllComponents and expecting that everything should be displayed properly. But you're still displaying pickerView from previous view controller. You should try to hide picker view on previous view controller's viewWillDisappear method and display new one in viewDidAppear method of new view controller.

Comment: sorry about the late reply ... holiday season. It appears that I am calling the same PickerView as when the unwind segue calls viewDidLoad() method again and has a new reference (so im guessing new instance of pickerView) and the new reference is passed to a new instance of the dataSource. Unfortunate, was hoping that would be it.

Comment: I have shown this to various colleagues that came back from holidays. None of which could resolve this, so I scrapped it and tried a different approach. It seem like the unwind segue was a custom segue class that did this weird thing of calling viewDidLoad() method again after the unwind. The problem was in the navigation and the way the views were programatically being stacked up. Thanks for all your help!